# Как добавить рамку для веб-камеры в ангуляре?

Tags: css3, angular, angular2, web-camera

В своем проекте я использую `ngx-webcam` для того, чтобы позволить пользователю делать фото себя.

Каким образом можно добавить какой-нибудь контейнер с маркерами, чтобы пользователь мог понимать как будет сделано фото (видеть центр и края)?

Возможно ли сделать это с css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изображение из веб-камеры будет находиться (то есть, вписано) в центре рамки (viewport), заданной свойствами самого webcam, то есть `[width]` и `[height]`, соответственно пользователь будет видеть края изображения.

Таким образом, рекомендую и в `css`, и в свойства webcam задавать одни и те же значения размеров, тогда и крестик будет в центре и `css-рамка` вокруг viewport.

CSS выглядит вот таким образом:

```
webcam {
  position: absolute;
  width: 640px;  /* Ширина рамки. Это не свойство [width] компонента */
  height: 480px; /* Высота рамки */

  border-width: 4px; /* Ширина борта */
  border-color: red; /* Цвет */
  border-style: solid; /* Тип */
  border-radius: 5px; /* Радиус закругления углов */

  background: lightcyan; /* Цвет фона */  
}

/* Крестик (знак +) в середине рамки */
webcam:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: "+"; /*Можно использовать HEX-code любого символа*/
    font-size: 30px; /* размер символа */
    color: red; /*его цвет*/
    line-height: 480px; /* Межстрочный интервал. Выравнивание крестика по-вертикали */
    text-align: center; /* Выравнивание по-горизонтали */
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое за развернутый ответ! сделала под параметры веб-камеры(ширину и высоту), но столкнулась с проблемой то, что при попытке открытия на телефоне рамка слишком большая

Comment: @ChihiroOgino попробуйте задать как отдельный вопрос, с примером проблемы с которой вы столкнулись при запуске на телефоне. Так будет понятнее и нагляднее, чем смешивать все вопросы в один